# One APK, multiple application modules

Tags: android

I have a project setup with 4 modules that flows like this
Module1 -> Module2 -> Module3
Module4

Module1 and Module4 are both entry points in to the app and need to have their own launch icons

Before I split the app in to modules this worked fine but when I split this into modules Modules 1 and 4 are are treated independent and I can either launch one or the other.

This is fine while developing the app but what I want at the end is to generate one APK that contains all modules and create 2 launcher icons when installed, but this isn't happening because it seems to generate 2 APKs

How do I need to organise this to generate one APK?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

It needs a bit more than just setting the intent filter so I thought I would explain it here in case anyone else is trying this.

Module1 is the application module, Module4 needs to be a library with just the bare definition for an activity.

Then in Module1 manifest you need to create an activity alias to Module4

The process is decribed well here..

http://blog.danlew.net/2014/01/16/preserve-your-launchers-use-activity-alias/

Also because of this Module1 now has a dependency on Module4 too

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file write this code at both entry point . it will generate two instance . for ex like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Activity.Your_module1_entry_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and for your second module

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Activity.your_module2_entry_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```